# How is there storage when I haven't signed in yet? Just reset phone

Tags: iphone, icloud, storage

Lots of problems with my iPhone. iTunes music skips like messed up cd, websites timeout, some apps click to download but they do nothing. Restrictions are off. Factory reset phone and I wasn't allowed to create a new Apple ID but before signing in my iCloud storage already showed 1.99 GB being used. I set up as new phone and not logged in any account prior to this. Hmmm. Any help?

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: what specific procedure did you take to factory reset? Are you looking for how to wipe a phone from iTunes without loading a back up? Please edit in a specific request - just because you aren't signed into iCloud now doesn't mean data didn't come from a backup or from a previous log in.

Answer (score 2):

Each of the apps you installed is taking up part of the 1.99 GB storage.

Even if you erase all content and settings - the OS and some baseline storage is used so you don't ever get 64 gb of available space.

- [What's the practical difference between a 16GB and 32GB iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64642/whats-the-practical-difference-between-a-16gb-and-32gb-iphone)
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/71313/5472